# libvlc vmem access violation

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, libvlc

I in my project use **paslibvlc** to get a video from *ip camera* that streaming   in h.264. I need to get a snapshots from this stream and try to use **vmem** for it. My project is written in *delphi 7*. When I connect to the camera with string "rtsp://ip/main" all is ok, but when I set callbacks and format it comes an error of *access memory violation*. Can somebody say to me, what i do wrong?
this is code

```
PBytes = ^TBytes;
TBytes = array of byte;

var
   MainForm: TMainForm;
   ctx:TBytes;

const
   cameraURL = 'rtsp://192.168.123.100/main';

function lock(opaque : Pointer; var planes : Pointer) : Pointer;
function unlock(opaque : Pointer; picture : Pointer; planes : Pointer) : Pointer;
function display(opaque : Pointer; picture : Pointer) : Pointer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


function lock(opaque : Pointer; var planes : Pointer) : Pointer;
begin
   planes := x;
end;

function unlock(opaque : Pointer; picture : Pointer; planes : Pointer) : Pointer;
begin
end;

function display(opaque : Pointer; picture : Pointer) : Pointer;
begin
end;

procedure TMainForm.PlayerInit();
var
  args: packed array[0..6] of PAnsiChar;
begin
  libvlc_dynamic_dll_init();

  SetLength(ctx, 1280*720*4+32);

  if (libvlc_dynamic_dll_error <> '') then
  begin
    MessageDlg(libvlc_dynamic_dll_error, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    exit;
  end;

   args[0] := PAnsiChar(libvlc_dynamic_dll_path);
   args[1] := '--no-video-title-show';
   args[2] := '--no-xlib';
   args[3] := '--no-audio';

  p_li := libvlc_new(Length(args)-1, @args[0]);
  p_mi := NIL;
end;

procedure TMainForm.PlayerPlay(fileName: WideString);
var
  p_md: libvlc_media_t_ptr;
begin
  btm:=Tbitmap.Create;
  btm.Width:=1280;
  btm.Height:=720;
  PlayerStop();

  // create new media from fileName
  p_md := libvlc_media_new_path(p_li, PAnsiChar(System.UTF8Encode(fileName)));

  //libvlc_media_player_set_media(p_mi, p_md);
  p_mi := libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(p_md);

  if (p_mi <> NIL) then
  begin
   libvlc_video_set_callbacks(p_mi,@lock,@unlock,@display,@ctx);
   libvlc_video_set_format(p_mi, 'RV32', 1280, 720, 1280*4);
    //libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(p_mi, btm.Handle);
  end;

  // play
  libvlc_media_player_play(p_mi);

  // release media
  if (p_md <> NIL) then
  begin
    libvlc_media_release(p_md);
    // p_md := NIL;
  end;
end;



procedure TMainForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PlayerInit();
  PlayerPlay(cameraURL);
end;
```

Comment: please, specify Delphi versions in tags. Thanks.  BTW why don't you make your avatara transparent ? white border in blue background just does not look sleek ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your callbacks use the `register` calling convention. But that's a Delphi specific calling convention. Your library uses `cdecl`. This can be seen from the Pascal source code for the library:

```
type
  libvlc_video_lock_cb    = function(opaque : Pointer; 
      var planes : Pointer) : Pointer; cdecl;
  libvlc_video_unlock_cb  = function(opaque : Pointer; 
      picture : Pointer; planes : Pointer) : Pointer; cdecl;
  libvlc_video_display_cb = function(opaque : Pointer; 
      picture : Pointer) : Pointer; cdecl;
```

You'll need to change your callbacks to match the library's calling convention.

The compiler would have told you all of this if only you had not used the `@` operator to obtain function pointers. Doing so means that the compiler will not check that your function pointers' signatures match the declared signatures. This is one of the most common errors that people make. For whatever reason, the myth has been perpetuated that the way to obtain a function pointer is to use the `@` operator.

In summary you need to add `cdecl` to your callback functions:

```
function lock(opaque : Pointer; var planes : Pointer) : Pointer; cdecl;
function unlock(opaque : Pointer; picture : Pointer; 
    planes : Pointer) : Pointer; cdecl;
function display(opaque : Pointer; picture : Pointer) : Pointer; cdecl;
```

And then stop using `@` to obtain function pointers:

```
libvlc_video_set_callbacks(p_mi, lock, unlock, display, @ctx);
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Yes it was my mistake that i don't declare callback function with cdecl. I made this, but i have similar error - access violation(

Comment: Here is little project, were I try to make this.  [PasLibVlcDemo](http://www.datafilehost.com/download-8c30c25d.html)

Comment: instead *cameraURL* possibly to use any video file on the PC

Comment: Sorry, I'm not in a position to debug a complete program. That's not really how SO works. You could ask another question if your latest problem is different from the question asked here.

Answer (score 0):

All problem was in how i allocate memory. In the first topic I allocate memory in locale memory of my program like SetLength(ctx, 1280*720*4+32), but for good work I have to use AllocMem to use Unmanaged memory.

Comment: No, the problem with the code in the question was exactly as I described. In the code in the question you never referred to `ctx`. So it was irrelevant at that point. Once you had fixed the problem in the code in the question, you then hit other problems. But since that code and those problems were not in the question they are not relevant. I'm very disappointed that you unaccepted my answer.

Comment: And, for what it is worth, you could perfectly well use `SetLength` to allocate your buffer. But to pass around a pointer to the first byte of the buffer you would use `@ctx[0]` rather than `@ctx`. All you had to do was ask a follow up question, and we could have sorted that out for you too.